# Android GridView: with default view in center

Tags: android, gridview

I am using a grid-view with base adapter. whenever the Activity opens the gridview should show with default view in middle and when user add items it should append i.e, it should come beside the the default view.

Here when clicking on the defaultview it starts different activity and click on other items opens different activity.

Below is my BaseAdapter

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<RowItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.rowItems = items;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);



            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.addcompany_layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            RowItem rowItem = (RowItem) getItem(position);


            holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(rowItem.getImagepath()));
                return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return rowItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowItems.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }
}
```

Below is my Activity

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addcompanytogrid_layout);
       // Bitmap homeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.add);
        //String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.add;

        Uri otherPath =Uri.parse("android.resource://tabquote.mycompany.com.myquate/" + R.drawable.add);
        String imageUri = otherPath .toString();

        rowItemstodisplay = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        allitems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();

       // RowItem item = RowItem.getInstance();
        RowItem item = new RowItem();

        String im = item.getImagepath();
        String ti = item.getTitle();
        rowItemstodisplay.add(new RowItem(im,ti));
        RowItem item1 = new RowItem();

        item1.setImagepath(im);
        item1.setTitle("Add Company");
       rowItemstodisplay.add(item1);

        for (int i=0; i<rowItemstodisplay.size(); i++) {
            allitems.add(rowItemstodisplay.get(i));
        }

        listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);
        CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItemstodisplay);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Unable to get the default view..items are adding but not sure how to implement defaultview

Comment: add activity code

Comment: added activity code

Answer (score 0):

why are you defining viewgroup null here

```
  convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.addcompany_layout, null);
```

instead of this add

```
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.addcompany_layout,parent,false);
```